# Firebase Google SignIn: localhost not whitelisted

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-web

According to the documentation, localhost should be whitelisted with all ports: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6400741?authuser=0 - and I checked this in console and firebase and localhost is in deed whitelisted.

But when I try to do the following in Flutter web, I get a not whitelisted error:

```
final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn;
final googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn(); // This is where the error happens
```

```
Error: PlatformException(idpiframe_initialization_failed, Not a valid origin for the client: http://localhost:59386 has not been whitelisted for client ID XXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com. Please go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and whitelist this origin for your project's client ID., https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#error_codes, null)


    at Object.createErrorWithStack (http://localhost:59386/dart_sdk.js:4353:12)
    at Object._rethrow (http://localhost:59386/dart_sdk.js:37968:16)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:59386/dart_sdk.js:37962:13)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:59386/dart_sdk.js:37794:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:59386/dart_sdk.js:37800:13)
    at http://localhost:59386/dart_sdk.js:33309:9
```

Im using these dart dependencies:

```
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.2
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.3+1
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.6
```

And im using `https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.1.1/firebase-auth.js` - so this should all be up to date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So despite the documentation claiming that all ports are whitelisted, this is not true.

Running Flutter on port 5000 (which was pre-filled in https://console.developers.google.com/ but not mentioned in https://console.firebase.google.com/ the app works as expected.

[image]

To get IntelliJ to run Flutter on a specific port edit the run configuration and add `--web-port 5000` as additional arguments:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Damian! plus you cannot add other ports from the firebase console. That was of great help